# Installing curved shower rod in standing shower stall

Tags: bathroom, shower, installation, trim

Can I put screws in the molding of our standing shower stall in order to install curved shower rod?

Comment: HI Corinne, a picture would help people answer it better.

Comment: Recommended only if there's a stud behind the wall, otherwise the torque of the (wet) curtain on the rod will cause the fasteners to loosen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can. The attachment method will depend on the molding material and its thickness, and perhaps on the type of wall that sits behind the molding. I recommend drilling pilot holes prior to attempting to screw into the molding, using stainless-steel screws (so they don't rust), and sealing them up with caulk so water does not run into the wall.